# Raspberry Pi as Desktop PC, NAS and Web-server simultaneously

Tags: pi-4

I literally got the **RPie 4** yesterday and have set up **Plex Media Server** on it. I have a external harddrive attached to it. Everything works fine and I an able to browse internet as a desktop!

I am now planning to setup **OpenMediaVault (OMV)** to turn the attached external drive into a **NAS Drive** and use the OMV Plex plugin for Plex Media Server. 
The instructions shown flashes the SDCard so I am afraid I will lose the ability to browse it as a desktop.

Here is the config I want: to set it up as OMV NAS and Plex Server but still be able to use the RPie as a desktop and be able to install apps etc. Is that possible?
Noob here, any feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an Rpi 4 and mine is also running Plex Media Server. I use it as a NAS as well, but I do this by running Samba on the Pi. No need for flashing anything.

Comment: Thanks! Eventually I did the same! I wanted the full blown OMV but then I would have to flash it so Samba suites my case.

Comment: Currently my pi4 is running Samba, mindlna, Tor proxy for my LAN, Transmission torrent client, and sbnzbd (Usenet nzb dlownloader).